# classification of morphism between varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field.

We have different important theorems to study morphism of variety, in particular there is a clear and constructive description of the morphism between affine variety

> Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_K$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{A}^m_K$ be affine varieties (my definition of affine variety don’t require the irreducibility). We know that a morphism $f: U \subseteq X\to Y$ with $U$ open is exactly of the form $f=(\phi_1, \dots , \phi_m):U \to Y$ where $\phi_i \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for all $i$.

There is a clear and constructive description of the morphism between projective spaces

> $f: \mathbb{P}ⁿ \to \mathbb{P}^m $ is of the form $$x \to (f_0(x):\dots : f_m(x))$$ with $f_0,\dots , f_m \in K[x_0,\dots ,x_n]$ homogeneous polynomials of the same degree such that $V_p(f_0,\dots , f_m)=\emptyset$. Furthermore if $n>m$ then $f$ is constant.

So I am curious to know if there exist theorems that can describe general morphism of the form

- $f: X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n \to Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^m$
- $ f: X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n \to Y \subseteq \mathbb{A}^m$
- $f: X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n \to Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^m$

where $X, Y$ are affine or projective varieties.

Comment: I wrote an answer here but it was deleted for an unknown reason. I write this as a comment since I am not giving any details. There is a proposition (in Hartshorne CH II.7.12) that relates maps to projective space to global sections of invertible sheaves. This notion makes sense in the language of "classical algebraic varieties" intorduced in HH CH I. Hence you must introduce sheaves and sheaves of modules in the language of HH CH I and prove this proposition in the language of classical algebraic varieties.

Comment: If $X$ is a quasi projective algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ as in CH I, you may define for any open subset $U \subseteq X$ the ring  $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ of regular functions on $U$. Given an inclusion of open sets $V \subseteq U$ you get canonical restriction maps $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(V)$ and you may prove this is a sheaf of $k$-algebras on $X$. Then you may introduce the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and the "tautological sequence" $\phi: \mathcal{O}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)$ on projective $n$ space.

Comment: Then you may prove an analogue of Prop II.7.12 in this classical language.